# How to had foreign key

Tags: database, entity-framework, asp.net-core, foreign-keys

(lol).

For who I know I been working (for training) on a pokemon database.

I have a problem with my database creation.

I have 18 different types :

```js
"Acier" 
"Combat" 
"Dragon" 
"Eau" 
"Electrik" 
"Fee" 
"Feu" 
"Glace" 
"Insecte" 
"Normal" 
"Plante" 
"Poison" 
"Psy" 
"Roche" 
"Sol" 
"Spectre" 
"Tenebre" 
"Vol"
```

A pokemon can have one OR two types :

Example :

- Pickachu type Electrik.
- Bulbizarre type Plante and Poison.

I try to use foreign key for create my database but I don't know how to do it please help.

I have a Pokemon model class:

```js
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Pokemon.Models
{
    [Table("Pokemons")]
    public class Pokemon
    {
        [Key]
        public int PokemonId { get; set; }

        [StringLength(30)]
        public string PokemonName { get; set; }

        [StringLength(30)]
        public string PokemonUsName { get; set; }

        [StringLength(30)]
        public string PokemonDeName { get; set; }

        [StringLength(30)]
        public string PokemonJpName { get; set; }

        public string PokemonDescription { get; set; }

        public int PokemonRate { get; set; }

        public string PokemonImage { get; set; }

        public int PokemonTypeId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("PokemonType")]
        public virtual PokemonType PokemonType { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And a PokemonType model class:

```js
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Pokemon.Models
{
    [Table("PokemonTypes")]
    public class PokemonType
    {
        [Key]
        public int TypeId { get; set; }

        [StringLength(8)]
        public string Type { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Pokemon> Pokemons { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I hope I asked my question clearly.

I want to make a pokemon "Bulbizarre" whit Type1Id = 7   //7for plante
And type2Id = 24 //24 for poison.

But some of them have only one type : type1Id 13 //13 for Electrik
and Type2Id = null. //because no second type.
[Table PokemonTypes screen from databse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTGdB.png)

Comment: This is not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Make your post self-contained.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.). PS Clearly there is non-minimal code/data here. (But much missing.) PS Code snippets are for css/html/javascript. See the edit help re code blocks. Look at the formatted version of your post below the edit box before you post.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is one bug in your code listing, The `[ForeignKey]` attribute can be put on the foreign key property or the navigation property, but if on the Navigation property it needs to be set to point to the FK field name. (PokemonTypeId)

Two options to support more than one pokemon type: 
If a Pokemon can have 1 or 2, but at max 2 types, then you can add two PokemonType references to the Pokemon. For example:

```
    public int PrimaryPokemonTypeId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("PrimaryPokemonTypeId")]
    public virtual PokemonType PrimaryPokemonType { get; set; }
    public int? SecondaryPokemonTypeId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("SecondaryPokemonTypeId")]
    public virtual PokemonType SecondaryPokemonType { get; set; }
```

If you can possibly refer to more than 2 types then you can adopt a many-to-many relationship rather than a 1 to many relationship. You can restrict the # of related types in code to two if you wish, but the data schema will support any number of types on a Pokemon.

A Pokemon would hold a collection of types. This means introducing a linking table. I.e. A PokemonTypePokemon.

If this is EF Core then you need to define the linking table:

```
public class Pokemon
{
    // ... Pokemon fields...

    public virtual ICollection<PokemonTypePokemon> PokemonTypes { get; set; } = new List<PokemonTypePokemon>();
}

public class PokemonType
{
    // Classifications...

    public virtual ICollection<PokemonTypePokemon> Pokemon { get; set; } = new List<PokemonTypePokemon>();
}    

public class PokemonTypePokemon
{
    public virtual Pokemon { get; set; }
    public virtual PokemonType { get; set; }
}
```

This will require a little wiring up in the DbContext to associate the linking table. In the DbContext's OnModelCreating handler...

```
// EF Core

modelBuilder.Entity<Pokemon>()
   .HasMany(x => x.PokemonTypes)
   .WithOne(x => x.Pokemon)
   .HasForeignKey("PokemonId");

modelBuilder.Entity<PokemonType>()
   .HasMany(x => x.Pokemon)
   .WithOne(x => x.PokemonType)
   .HasForeignKey("PokemonTypeId");
```

You will likely need to configure the PK for the PokemonTypePokemon table as well to use a composite key on PokemonId & PokemonTypeId.

With EF6 you can map a `HasMany().WithMany()`, without needing the map the joining table in many cases. This should give you some idea where to start with the mapping change and joining table. Do a bit of Google-fu on EF Many-to-Many to refine.

Answer (score 0):

I made it !
I made databse first and scaffold it!

[Database diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1h2Yv.png)
this make me 3 model class with everythings correct inside

```js
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace DataModels.Models
{
    public partial class Pokemons
    {
        public Pokemons()
        {
            PokemonsPokemonTypes = new HashSet<PokemonsPokemonTypes>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Num { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(30)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [StringLength(30)]
        public string UsName { get; set; }

        [StringLength(30)]
        public string JpName { get; set; }

        public int? Rate { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Image { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Kind { get; set; }

        public double? Height { get; set; }
        public double? Weight { get; set; }

        [InverseProperty("Pokemon")]
        public virtual ICollection<PokemonsPokemonTypes> PokemonsPokemonTypes { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```js
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace DataModels.Models
{
    public partial class PokemonsPokemonTypes
    {
        public int PokemonId { get; set; }
        public int TypeId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("PokemonId")]
        [InverseProperty("PokemonsPokemonTypes")]
        public virtual Pokemons Pokemon { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("TypeId")]
        [InverseProperty("PokemonsPokemonTypes")]
        public virtual PokemonTypes Type { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```js
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace DataModels.Models
{
    public partial class PokemonTypes
    {
        public PokemonTypes()
        {
            PokemonsPokemonTypes = new HashSet<PokemonsPokemonTypes>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }

        [StringLength(8)]
        public string Type { get; set; }

        [InverseProperty("Type")]
        public virtual ICollection<PokemonsPokemonTypes> PokemonsPokemonTypes { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This works pretty well!
One Product (Pokemon) can have Multipke Categories (Type).